# How to cast a scala.xml.NodeSeq to a Elem?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to reduce a list of elements

```
List(1, 2, 3).map{n => <a>{n}</a>}.reduce{(a,b)=> a ++ b}
```

But I get this error

```
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.xml.NodeSeq
 required: scala.xml.Elem
       List(1, 2, 3).map{n => <a>{n}</a>}.reduce{(a,b)=> a ++ b}
```

How do I cast a NodeSeq to a Elem?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `reduce` in this case.  Instead, try `foldLeft`:

```
List(1, 2, 3).map{n => <a>{n}</a>}.foldLeft(NodeSeq.Empty){(a,b)=> a ++ b}
```

I have [a whole blog post](http://proseand.co.nz/2013/09/09/map-reduce-and-fold-for-the-programmatically-imperative/) on `map`, `reduce`, and `fold` that may help if you're new to functional programming.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to joescii's answer, you don't even need to use `foldLeft` to generate a sequence of nodes. Since `List` is already a sequence and `Seq[Node]` which is implicitly converted to `NodeSeq` you can just write the following:

```
val x : NodeSeq = List(1, 2, 3).map{n => <a>{n}</a>}
```

In addition, since the sequence of nodes is not a valid XML document (breaks single root element contract), you'd probably use this as a interim step in generating XML and subsequently wrap those nodes with some parent element.

If that's the case, than the explicit conversion to `NodeSeq` is unnecessary as it will be done implicitly as the example below demonstrates:

```
val x = List(1, 2, 3).map{n => <a>{n}</a>}
<b>{x}</b>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answer, the simplest way to convert `NodeSeq` to `Elem` is:

```
val elemVar = nodeSeqVal(0)
```

It works if you are definitely sure that there are always the only Node in your NodeSeq, otherwise you lost the rest of the data.